# PHP: Array passed by reference to a function?

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I have this php function that has to perform some processing on a given array:

```
processArray($arrayToProcess) {

  $arrayToProcess['helloStackOverflow'] = TRUE;
}
```

Later, the code invokes the following:

```
$niceArray = array('key' => 'value');
processArray($niceArray);
```

The key 'helloStackOverflow' isn't available outside the processArray function. I tried calling the following:

```
processArray(&$niceArray);
```

Using "&" helps, however it raises some warning:

> Deprecated function: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated; If you would like to pass it by reference, modify the declaration of populateForm_withTextfields()

Tried the & in there, but that just stops the code.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to define the reference in the function, not in the call to the function.

```
function processArray(&$arrayToProcess) {
```

Answer (score 8):

```
processArray(&$arrayToProcess) {

  $arrayToProcess['helloStackOverflow'] = TRUE;
}
```

implements the reference in PHP way.

See https://www.php.net/references for useful information about references.

Answer (score 5):

```
processArray(&$arrayToProcess) {

  $arrayToProcess['helloStackOverflow'] = TRUE;
}
```

Referencing passing now takes place at the function declaration, not when the function is called.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

for full documentation.